# Jenkins build fails on slaves with java.lang.InterruptedException

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins build fails with `Cannot contact XXXXXXXXXXXX: java.lang.InterruptedException`

from time to time. it doesn't matter if it is a spot instance or an on-demand instance

```
Jenkins ver. 2.60.3 
Amazon EC2 plugin 1.36
```

Comment: They already shared the ssh-keys

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I monitored the slave stats and figured out that the slave was under heavy load like 1200. The slaves build a lot of docker images. The load was due to the fact that the save was I/O bound. The docker volume `/var/lib/docker` and `workspace` were `EBS` and `EFS` mounts respectively.  Upgrading the linux kernel and changing the docker volume to `Overlay2` solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

In my case after the error described above in the pipeline, I checked the specific node console log and it appeared the following error:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Ping started on XXXX hasn't completed at XXX
```

Probably the jenkins slave was corrupted. Just rebooting the slave solved the problem as it is explained in this [jenkins issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14307)